# Bypass website that falls under wildcard proxy exception

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy, http-proxy

I need a way to exclude a specific web address from the Win 10 list of proxy exceptions.

For example, if I am using a proxy, but I don't want the proxy used for a specific domain (google.com) I can add "*.google.com" to the list of excepted addresses in proxy settings as shown below. But what if I do want to use the proxy for any addresses that start with "maps.google.com". Is there a way to have an exception to the list of exceptions?

What I would like to do (use something like a "-" to bypass maps.google.com from exclusion):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do that via *Control Panel > Internet Options*, to set up a rule
to use a proxy script.

In the resulting dialog, click the *Connections* tab and then on *LAN settings*
at the bottom. Next tick *Use automatic configuration script* and enter the
name of a local `proxy.pac` file, which will contain a script
that you will need to write.

[image]

Please note that local
proxy scripts are deprecated but may still be enabled by changing the registry.
For details, see the article
[Understanding Web Proxy Configuration](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2013/10/11/understanding-web-proxy-configuration/)
for setting
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\EnableLegacyAutoProxyFeatures`.

Creating a `proxy.pac` file needs some knowledge. See for example
[Wikipedia Proxy auto-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config),
but much more information is available by searching on the Web.

Comment: It is not correct that "proxy scripts are deprecated". It is true that *local* proxy scripts *defined by the `file://` syntax* had been deprecated, but these have now also been removed, see also https://superuser.com/a/1569042/253137. You can still serve a local `.pac` file through a local HTTP server, for example.