# Is there a way to set up a proxy (address) on Windows 7 only for some country sites?

Tags: windows-7, proxy

How to set up a proxy address not for all sites but, for example, for all `*.*.it` sites. So I need to use only the country part.
It is better for me to use Windows 7 settings (maybe `cmd`) instead of a program.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using a proxy for certain sites only](https://superuser.com/questions/417896/using-a-proxy-for-certain-sites-only)

Comment: @music2myear No, it doesn't.

Comment: You'll probably want to use a proxy auto configuration (PAC) script for this, coupled with a group policy for Windows 7 PCs only.  The PAC script can contain conditional rules for each site.  For example, `function FindProxyForURL(url, host) { if (host.match(/\.it$/)) return 'PROXY ITPROXY:8080'; if (host.match(/\.cn$/)) return 'PROXY CNPROXY:8081'; return 'PROXY DEFAULTPROXY:80; DIRECT'; }`

Comment: @leeharvey1 Yes, cool. Where to add this in Windows 7?

Comment: Save it to a .pac file.  Host the .pac file on an intranet web server for Windows 7 PCs.  Set the .pac file URL in Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Connections tab > LAN settings > [X] Use automatic configuration script, Address field.  Enforce this IE setting via group policy -- which is beyond the scope (See [this](https://techexpert.tips/windows/gpo-proxy-auto-configuration-script/) and [this](https://theitbros.com/config-internet-explorer-11-proxy-settings-gpo/), [etc](http://woshub.com/configure-internet-explorer-10-and-11-settings-using-gpo-in-windows-server-2012/))

Comment: @leeharvey1 I don't use Internet Explorer. Will it work in Chrome? And I don't have a web server.

Comment: Yes, Chrome obeys Internet Explorer's proxy setting.  However, use of local `file://` URL hosting for .pac files is now considered unsafe, and [may now be deprecated](https://superuser.com/questions/191037/local-pac-file-url-format-that-works-with-ie-and-safari-windows).  FYI, most proxy servers themselves may allow .pac file hosting. ;)

Comment: @leeharvey1 *FYI, most proxy servers themselves may allow .pac file hosting* — but how to know if it is and do that? I just take a free proxy address from a site.